# How to split values from pandas dataframe columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with multiple columns, two of them being Sensor and Value. These values are recorded in a given location, which is also included in the dataframe, and also the time of the recording. They look like this:

```
Sensor      Value Time Location...
humidity    56    x    y
temperature 23    x    z
ozone       2
pm25        10
co2         20
co2         21
pm25        0
pm10        1
...
```

How can I extract the sensor names (as columns in the new dataframe) and create the column with the corresponding values? The column names being: humidity, temperature, ozone... and the values their corresponding ones.

Comment: Is that what you are looking for? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

Comment: Something similar, but I would like to mantain the variable type as dataframe.